# Is Xamarin.Forms a simple sum of Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.IoS and Xamarin.Win?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Is Xamarin.Forms considered a simple sum of Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.IoS with a shared code library wrapper? or is there more under the hood than meets the eye?

I am not talking about the shared code library because I realize it is specific to Xamarin.Forms but rather (for example) if I am to compare a Xamarin.Droid project to an android codebase of a Xamarin.Forms solution, will I find any considerable differences? Will I find any differences. Same goes for IoS & Windows...

Just to provide context; I am interested in utilizing some tools which were originally designed for Xamarin.android however my projects are Xamarin.forms solutions and it would be cool to know in advance if I am running into a rathole.

Thanks in advance you fine people.

Comment: no, it is not simply the "sum" of it's parts.  It adds a number of additional features of it's own, and it also has some limitations in that it can't fully take advantage of features that exist on only one platform.  But this is a really broad question that can't be meaningfully answered on SO

Comment: Ok, that makes sense but that doesn't indicate wether or not a xamarin.droid project is considered equivalent to the android codebase of a xamarin.forms solution. Does this extra complexity exist in the android codebase?

Comment: "equivalent" meaning what?  But generally the Android project in a Forms solution is going to consist of Xamarin Android code, although it may utilize Forms features like MessagingCenter or DependencyService, etc

Comment: By equivalence I mean that with the exception of custom renderers and dependency services could a droid portion of a xamarin.forms solution be ported without issues to a regular xamarin.droid project?

Comment: Generally, yes.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I'll give you a vote if you want to put it in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin Forms, in the end, is a wrapper over the native API's so if you have something in Xamarin Forms you can of course port it to Xamarin Android, iOS or Windows.

> Is Xamarin.Forms considered a simple sum of Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.IoS with a shared code library wrapper? or is there more under the hood than meets the eye?

At its simplest, Xamarin.Forms is a mobile application framework for building user interfaces. The definition from Xamarin's website is:

Xamarin.Forms is a cross-platform UI toolkit that allows developers to easily create native user interface layouts that can be shared across Android, iOS, and Windows Phone.

But don't simply focus on the term "UI" in that definition and think only on-screen controls. Instead, focus on the word "toolkit" as Xamarin. Forms offer so much more in addition to user interface controls that work across platforms.

Xamarin.Forms will emit a 100% native iOS, Android or UWP app – in fact the starting point of any Xamarin.Forms app is within one of those platform projects. However, that's as far as the platform-specific code needs to go. The rest of the code can all be written in one of the layers that are shared amongst all the applications.

> if I am to compare a Xamarin.Droid project to an android codebase of a Xamarin.Forms solution, will I find any considerable differences? Will I find any differences. Same goes for IoS & Windows...

Just Basic API differences, which are different between forms and native

Answer (score 1):

You shoud see Xamarin.Forms as the abstraction of the UI over the actual platform. Xamarin.Forms (XF) renders the UI in native platforms controls, but they are created using XF XAML.

Coding against XF is like coding for a different platform with a different set of tools, at the UI level!

You can, if needed go deep in platform specific details if needs be via interface implementation and injection.